# How should I deal with these DB entities when using OOP?

Tags: oop, design-patterns, database-design, mapping, entity-relationship

Say I have this ER Diagram:

[image: ER Diagram]

How should I proceed when creating the classes? Should I create a **Species** class with a *list of Breeds*, or a **Breed** class with a *Species attribute*? 
I don't know yet how the business logic will unfold, but I assume that I'll have to deal with both situations: I may have to retrieve a list of all Breeds belonging to a Species, or the Species to which a Breed belongs.

I know there is not a single answer to this, but any pointer in the right direction would be appreciated.

Comment: It probably mostly depends on the actual concrete ORM you're using. In JPA, you would use a bidirectional association, for example.

Comment: In entity-relationship and relational modeling, relationships are undirected so you don't need to choose.  Your problem is that you're using OOP to represent the business domain instead of using it for what it's good for - building interacting services that know and communicate about the business domain.  Objects encapsulate data but objects aren't data.